# Get closest date to given date for a group of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Hi guys I'm having problems with a sql query, look, this is my scenario:

I have an students table and a table where I store dates when students enter or leave the school, so I want to get the nearest date to a given date for every student, I can't find the way to do this.

```
Students Data:

|idstudent|name  |
------------------
|    1    | John |
|    2    | Bob  |
------------------

Dates Data: 

|id|idstudent|   date   |type|
------------------------------
|1 |   1     |20-01-2015| 1  |
|2 |   2     |20-01-2015| 1  |
|3 |   2     |15-08-2015| 2  |
|4 |   1     |31-08-2015| 2  |
------------------------------

Desired Date = 01-08-2015 

|idstudent| name  | date       |type|
-------------------------------------
|    1    | John  | 31-08-2015 | 2  |
|    2    | Bob   | 15-08-2015 | 2  |
```

Students Table:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
  idstudent serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(200),
  CONSTRAINT idstudent PRIMARY KEY (idstudent)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE students
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Dates Table:

```
CREATE TABLE students_dates
(
  idstudent_date serial NOT NULL,
  idstudent bigint,
  date_ date,
  type smallint,
  CONSTRAINT idstudent_date PRIMARY KEY (idstudent_date)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE students_dates
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please **edit** your question, add the table definition, some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data. It would be perfect if you can also create a http://sqlfiddle.com example

Comment: Sorry I'm new, is the post OK now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the proprietary `distinct on ()` is usually faster in Postgres than using window functions.

Building on Gordon's idea with the abs():

```
select distinct on (s.idstudent) s.*, sd.date_, sd.type
from students s
  join students_dates sd on s.idstudent = sd.idstudent
order by s.idstudent, abs(sd.date_ - date '2015-09-26');
```

This can also be solved using a Window function:

```
select idstudent, name, date_, type
from (
  select s.idstudent, s.name, sd.date_, sd.type, 
         row_number() over (partition by s.idstudent order by sd.date_ - date '2015-09-26' desc) as rn
  from students s
    join students_dates sd on s.idstudent = sd.idstudent
) t
where rn = 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/25fef/4

Comment: Thanks! @a_horse_with_no_name, I used the first query

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF` to get difference between dates, get `ABS` value. Then sort by `ABS(DATEDIFF())` and get top record.

Comment: There is no `datediff()` in Postgres

Comment: I know how to get the closest date to a given date but what I don't understand is how to do it for a group of records

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky.  I think the best method is `distinct on`.  You don't describe the data in your question, but this is the idea:

```
select distinct on (studentid) s.*
from students s
order by studentid, abs(studentdate - '2015-09-26');
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your request , this is the answer.
It joins the students table with the students dates table after its RANKED and takes only the date nearest to your GIVEN_DATE.

```
SELECT s.* FROM students s
INNER JOIN
(SELECT date,type FROM (
 SELECT sd2.*,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sd2.idstudent ORDER BY abs(sd2.date - GIVEN_DATE) ASC) as sdrank
 FROM students_dates sd2
 ) where sdrank = 1) sd on sd.idstudent = s.idstudent
```

Comment: There are much simpler ways to use `row_number()` or `rank()` to solve this problem.  You might want to think about other methods.  (Hint:  a `join` is not necessary.)

Comment: Just tell me exactly how a join is not necessary if the guy is using two diffrent tables. If i understood currectly, the dates table can have more then 1 record for each student and he want to join the student table with the nearest record by date

Comment: I added some data to the post, sorry!

Comment: Edited my answer, just change GIVEN_DATE to your date

Comment: Thanks @sagi I'll try it

Comment: No problem,Had a syntax problem, fixed it, I dont have the tools to check it so tell me if it works.

Comment: Syntax problems: I have to add an alias here `FROM students_dates sd2
 ) **X** ` and I need to add idstudent on the subquery for the join. For my purpose I just want to return only ONE date from the dates table so I used  `DISTINCT ` and removed the type column, it looks like this now  `INNER JOIN (SELECT idstudent,  date FROM ...` , and I'll add an `INNER JOIN` below to get the `type`, I don't know if theres a better way to achieve this. Btw, sorry for my bad english haha.

Comment: I'd be tempted to add in a tie-breaker as well, to avoid non-determinate result sets where two records were closest, one after and one before. So where that situation exists, you always choose the later one for example.

Comment: I think what Gordon wanted to point out is that only _one_ join is needed, not two.